# Loop over two arrays of objects, connect and merge them on Id

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I am fairly new to javascript and have been looking for an example that matches what i'm trying to do, but am having trouble finding a solution. I have two arrays of objects structured like so:

*Note: There will never be duplicate subId's within the subscriptionArray.

```
subscriptionArray = [
  {
    "subId" : 100,
    "companyId" : 5,
    "companyName" : "CompanyA",
    "domain" : "companyA.com"
  },
  {
    "subId" : 200,
    "companyId" : 6,
    "companyName" : "CompanyB",
    "domain" : "companyB.com"
  },
  {
    "subId" : 300,
    "companyId" : 5,
    "companyName" : "CompanyA",
    "domain" : "companyA.com"
  },

]

userArray = [
  {
    "name" : "John",
    "companyId" : 5,
    "email" : "john@companyA.com"      
  },
  {
    "Name" : "Frank",
    "CompanyId" : 5,
    "Email" : "Frank@companyA.com"     
  },
  {
    "name" : "Bill",
    "companyId" : 6,
    "email" : "bill@companyB.com"

  }

 ]
```

My intended result array is as follows. My goal is, loop over every subscription, then loop over every user, return every user that has a companyId that matches a subscription's companyId. So subId 100 and 300 are returned twice since companyA has 2 users.

```
resultArray = [
 {
  "subId" : 100,
  "companyId" : 5,
  "companyName" : "CompanyA",
  "domain" : "companyA.com",
  "name" : "John",
  "email" : "john@companyA.com"
 },
 {
  "subId" : 100,
  "companyId" : 5,
  "companyName" : "CompanyA",
  "domain" : "companyA.com",
  "name" : "Frank",
  "email" : "frank@companyA.com"
 },
 {
  "subId" : 200,
  "companyId" : 6,
  "companyName" : "CompanyB",
  "domain" : "companyB.com",
  "name" : "Bill",
  "email" : "bill@companyB.com"
 },
 {
  "subId" : 300,
  "companyId" : 5,
  "companyName" : "CompanyA",
  "domain" : "companyA.com",
  "name" : "John",
  "email" : "john@companyA.com"
 },
 {
  "subId" : 300,
  "companyId" : 5,
  "companyName" : "CompanyA",
  "domain" : "companyA.com",
  "name" : "Frank",
  "email" : "frank@companyA.com"
 },

]
```

I am trying something like this.

```
var newArray = [];    

subscriptionArray.forEach(function(subscription) {
  companyIdA = subscription.companyId;

  userArray.forEach(function(user) {
    companyIdB = user.companyId;
    if(companyIdB === companyIdA) {

        //Below I am trying to add a key 'subId' to the user 
        //object before pushing it to newArray.

      user.subId = subscription.subId;
      newArray.push(user)
    }

  })
})
```

So the code above is returning the correct amount of results, but it is obviously just returning the user object information and not any information from the subscriptionArray. I tried to add in a new key/value for subId before pushing the object into the newArray, but this just ends up repeating the same subId for every similar company(I believe because it's looping over one subscription, then the entire userArray, then goes to the next subscription, but the subId isn't being changed.)

I am working with a larger data set, about 40 subscriptions and 6 companies and I am just trying to get one single array of objects where each object is a user, associated with a company, associated with a subscription(which would make subscriptionId's repeat if a company has multiple users).

Environment: Google Apps Script. I am trying to not use jQuery and I believe GAS doesn't support LoDash. So if anyone has a solution in vanilla JS that would be perfect!

Comment: You have a 1 to 1 relationship between the subscription and user arrays, you should save a property of user_id on your subscription array to join the data. It doesn't make sense to join on the company_id as it's not a unique key, you could only really group the users by the company_id

Comment: Yea that's kind of my issue, it's kind of like the subId is the unique_key and i'm just trying to return all the users from the company that purchased that subscription. In theory it's kind of like, go through every single subscription, and for each subscription pull the companyId. Then look at the userArray, if there is a user or multiple users with that companyId, return them all into a newArray. I have that working, but I can't seem to get the correct subId to also be pushed into the object that was pulled out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can loop through the subscriptions and use [`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for the associated user based on matching company ID. Using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) lets you merge  objects

**Edit:** reverted to ES5 methods only due to lack of support for newer methods

```js
var companyUsers = {}// hashmap of users using companyId as keys

userArray.forEach(function(user){
  companyUsers[user.companyId] = user;
});

// map new array based on each subscription
var res = subscriptionArray.map(function(sub){
  var user = companyUsers[sub.companyId];  
  if(user){
    for(var key in user){
      sub[key] = user[key]
    }
  }
  return sub;
});

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
var subscriptionArray = [
  {
    "subId" : 100,
    "companyId" : 5,
    "companyName" : "CompanyA",
    "domain" : "companyA.com"
  },
  {
    "subId" : 200,
    "companyId" : 6,
    "companyName" : "CompanyB",
    "domain" : "companyB.com"
  },
  {
    "subId" : 300,
    "companyId" : 5,
    "companyName" : "CompanyA",
    "domain" : "companyA.com"
  },

]

var userArray = [
  {
    "name" : "John",
    "companyId" : 5,
    "email" : "john@companyA.com"      
  },
  {
    "Name" : "Frank",
    "CompanyId" : 5,
    "Email" : "Frank@companyA.com"     
  },
  {
    "name" : "Bill",
    "companyId" : 6,
    "email" : "bill@companyB.com"

  }

 ]
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie, unfortunately Google Apps Script can be pretty limited in the javascript methods allowed. Especially with keeping up with the new ES6 changes. I get the error "Cannot find function find in object [object Object],[object Object], [object Object]"

Comment: Can you test it also to see if it supports `Object.assign()`? Can rewrite this as needed. A simple test of `var someVar = Object.assign({},{foo:'bar'})` would tell

Comment: Unfortunately it throws the same error, but with the "Cannot find function assign in Object{}..."

Comment: Ok...suspected so if `find()` didn't work. Give me a couple of minutes to rewrite

Comment: Try new dummied down version. It is modifying original subscription objects. Can change that if needed

Comment: So it looks like it's partially working! It's the right key/values returned, but it doesn't look like it's creating a new object for John for subId 100 and 300. When I ran it, I got 3 objects back, with subId 100 and 300 only returning Frank for both. But what I'm trying to return is multiple objects for those two subId's because the company assigned has multiple users

Comment: I logged companyUsers and got: {5={companyId=5.0, name=Frank, email=Frank@companyA.com}, 6={companyId=6.0, name=Bill, email=bill@companyB.com}}. So maybe John isn't getting added into company 5?

Comment: Oh...you have multiple users with same companyId? Wasn't looking at that. If so how should it work?

Comment: Exactly, yea that's my problem. A company can have multiple subscriptions and multiple users. It's hard to explain, but imagine a company purchases a subscription and that company happened to have two employees. Ideally I could then have two objects with repeating subId's and companyId's but with different employee names. On and on through every subscription. A company has 20 employees, then I would have 20 objects with the same subId's and companyId's but different employee names. And if that 20 person company has multiple subscriptions, just repeat all 20 employees but with that subId.

Comment: So if a company has 5 subscriptions, their employees names will be repeated 5 different times but their subId would be matched to that instance of a subscription

Comment: How about an array of users for each sub then? `{
    "subId" : 100,
    "companyId" : 5,
    "companyName" : "CompanyA", "users":[{joe}, {bill}]}`

Comment: I think that would be fine! My end goal is to print this array to a spreadsheet, so I think as long as I have some sort of data set with that info, I should be able to write it to the spreadsheet. I think if I could get it structured like you have above, I could do a double loop and print out all of them as their own line

Comment: Or perhaps add additional info to each user for their subscriptions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the last comment, but is it possible to turn my two arrays into the nested array like you wrote out above?

Comment: That worked great Charlie, thanks for sticking with me! I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

```
 const byId = new Map();

 for(const {companyId, ...user} of userArray){
  const users = byId.get(companyId)
  if(users){
    users.push(user);
  } else {
    byId.set(companyId, [user]);
  }
 }

 const result = [];

  for(const subscription of subscriptionArray)
    for(const user of byId.get(subscription.companyId))
       result.push({ ...user, ...subscription });
```

This uses a companyId hashtable, which may makes it more performant.

Comment: I get a syntax error on the first line of the for loop. What is the ...user doing? Is there possibly another way to write this?